# Android native Parcel usage

Tags: android, c++, native, parcel

I am trying out Parcel with native code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <binder/IInterface.h>
#include <binder/Parcel.h>
#include <binder/IBinder.h>
#include <binder/Binder.h>
#include <binder/ProcessState.h>
#include <binder/IPCThreadState.h>
#include <binder/IServiceManager.h>

using namespace android;

int main()
{
  int32_t i = 123, j = 456;

  Parcel data;
  status_t t = data.writeInt32(j);
  if(t == NO_ERROR)
    printf("Status: %d\n", t);
  else if(t == BAD_VALUE)
    printf("Bad Value\n");

  int32_t jj = 0;
  t = data.readInt32(&jj);
  printf("t: %d\n", t);
  printf("ParcelTest: %d\n", jj);

  return 0;
}
```

To compile this code, Android's source tree is needed. Put it under external/ParcelTest. And the Android.mk is [here](https://pastebin.com/TtT2RnG4). Run `mmma external/ParcelTest` to compile.

Output of the program is:

```
generic_x86:/ # /system/bin/ParcelTest
Status: 0
t: -61
ParcelTest: 0
```

The `Status: 0` indicates that writing value into the Parcel works out. But reading doesn't. So Parcel is the thing that if I read data as the order I write, I would get correct result. Any idea why this code sample fails?

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <binder/IInterface.h>
#include <binder/Parcel.h>
#include <binder/IBinder.h>
#include <binder/Binder.h>
#include <binder/ProcessState.h>
#include <binder/IPCThreadState.h>
#include <binder/IServiceManager.h>

using namespace android;

int main()
{
  int32_t i = 123, j = 456;

  Parcel data;
  status_t t = data.writeInt32(j);
  if(t == NO_ERROR)
    printf("Status: %d\n", t);
  else if(t == BAD_VALUE)
    printf("Bad Value\n");

  int32_t jj = 0;
  data.setDataPosition(0);
  t = data.readInt32(&jj);
  printf("t: %d\n", t);
  printf("ParcelTest: %d\n", jj);

  return 0;
}
```

The read position has to be set manually.